# indirect function in data validation vba

Tags: vba, excel, validation, excel-indirect

I have just a litle big problem!

I do a macro with excel with two validation list, the first list is functional but with the INDIRECT function I have the cuestion.

the first list is in Cell b17

My second list must take the reference b17 to do the indirect function, but doesnt work, with the code I research is functional but dont dropdown the list in reference to B17 just "copy" the text in this cell.

This is my code

```
 Sub insertfamilyValidate()

' Selecciona la celda basica de indirecto

' insertfamilyValidate Macro
'
' Acceso directo: CTRL+f
'
    Rows("17:18").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A17:M17").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 39423
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Código"
    Range("B17:D17").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("A17").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("B17:D17").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Familias"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("E17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Pax Sentadas"
    Range("F17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cant."
    Range("G17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cost. Unit."
    Range("H17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Días"
    Range("I17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
    Range("J17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "%"
    Range("K17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Descuento"
    Range("L17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sub total"
    Range("M17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
    Range("A17:M17").Select
    Range("M17").Activate
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With

    Dim MiCelda As Range

Set MiCelda = Worksheets("cotizacion").Cells(17, 2)

With Range("A18").Validation
    ' clear previous validation to existing cell
    .Delete

    ' *** Added this debug part ***
    Dim ValidStr            As String
    ValidStr = "=INDIRECT(" & MiCelda.Address(True, True) & ")"
    Debug.Print ValidStr

   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & MiCelda.Address(True, True) & ")"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
    Range("B18:D18").Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,LISTAPRECIOS2016,2,FALSE)"
    Range("E18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,LISTAPRECIOS2016,3,FALSE)"
    Range("F18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("G18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,LISTAPRECIOS2016,9,FALSE)"
    Range("H18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("I18").Select
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
    Range("J18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("K18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
    Range("L18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]-RC[-1]"
    Range("M18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1])"
    Range("G18").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Range("I18").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Range("J18").Select
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    Range("K18").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Range("L18").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Range("M18").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Range("A18").Select
End Sub
```

I think the problem is that the result in Indirect is "$B$17", so, is a string if I do the Validate list in excel the result is =indirect($B$17) without quotation marks and this is funcional, I try to remove the quotes, the first time was ok but after that is a error 1004.

I know is a minimum error or my variable is wrong but i cant figure it.
Any help?

I add the .delete and the error is the same.

This is a screenshot

[image]

The screenshot with debug is here...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before you setup your `Validation Formula` you need to clear the previous one by adding the code line :

```
Range("A18").Validation.Delete
```

And for the full code (tested) :

```
Sub Validate()

Dim MiCelda As Range

Set MiCelda = Worksheets("cotizacion").Cells(17, 2)

With Range("A18").Validation
    ' clear previous validation to existing cell
    .Delete

    ' *** Added this debug part ***
    Dim ValidStr            As String
    ValidStr = "=INDIRECT(" & MiCelda.Address(True, True) & ")"
    Debug.Print ValidStr

   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & MiCelda.Address(True, True) & ")"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

The result I am getting in the immediate window is:

```
=INDIRECT($B$17)
```

Comment: thanks for your help but even with the .delete code is the same error code 1004...

Comment: @LadyMuerte but you didn't copy the next line,  of `.Add Type:=xlValidateList` ... without the """

Comment: i do it, but if I remove the quotes the function says error 1004, with the three quotes the function is complete but with the content of cell b17 in a18

Comment: @LadyMuerte see edited code , I've added a part to debug the formula, try it and let me know if you get the same result

Comment: I do it, and its the same result, even with the =INDIRECT($B$17) in the inmediate result the error is 1004.

Comment: I can't figure out why ? what do you have inside $B$17 ?

Comment: another validate list. if this change the product, A18 must change to another result.... same as use "indirect" in excel. I can post the code complete if you want for more reference

Comment: In your full code you are merging **Cells B17:D17** ? you have this line `Range("B17:D17").Select` , and after the `With Selection` you have the line `Selection.Merge` .

Comment: yes, that is because in the superior raws i have text, so, I have to merge the cells, In the next raw is the same, i have to merge B18:D18 too. It is a problem?

Comment: @Shau Rado... I try with not merge de cells... and is workin the first time... but again the error is in the same place

Comment: @LadyMuerte what cell reference do you have in your Cell B17 ?

Comment: I have the reference to =familias this is a range name, in other page in the same book